# What is being listed when typing 'conda list' into terminal?

Tags: python, module, anaconda, conda, environment

According to the documentation, conda list returns
"list of packages and versions installed in active environment"
But when I run this, I get things I recognise as packages, such as 'cairo', but also 'python' (version 3.7.3) itself, which is a language, and 'spyder' and 'jupyter', being interactive environments.

(Interestingly, python2 is not listed here, but is in the conda env list. The only reason I can think of for this is that the Anaconda version I am using (3) comes with python 2, and python 3 has been installed on top of this.)

I am trying to get my head around what each of these items is, and how I can access it when using different environments. The environments I have available are (base, omnipath, pypath, python2, rstudio). I am working within omnipath, and it seems to work fine to then run a script which in which I 'import pypath' (and yet both of these are environments!? These seems to me that they are on 'the same level', which is why I am unconfortable with the idea of caling one from the other).

In my script, I also need to call ipython, which is listed in conda list when in the base environment, but not when in omnipath or pypath. This seems to be a problem as I I obtain an error 'no module named IPython' because it is not in the 'conda list' when in this environment.

Since my script seems to be able to import pypath when in the omnipath environment, I thought that perhaps I could work 'from the base' and import omnipath as required too, and then IPython would work fine. Except I get an error 'no module named omnipath'.

I hope this illustarted my confusion: pypath is not listed as a module and is not present in 'conda list', and is listed as an environment. These facts are exactly the same as for omnipath.

And yet I am able to 'import pypath' and 'import ipython' and even 'import IPython' (still not sure why these are different) without error from the base and from the omnipath environment, but not from pypath.

I suspect that the most appropriate response to my queries is a link to understanding how these diffeent programming objects fit together,

Comment: Do you happen to have any files in any of your work directories called `pypath.py`? To answer your title question, `conda list` lists all of the packages installed in the environment, as the docs say. Python itself is installed from a package into the environment, as are Spyder and Jupyter. A package is just a collection of code files of one sort or another. But if you can try to clarify what you're asking here, it would help produce better answers. I'm quite confused what it is that you need to know :-)

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, "package" here means "conda package", not "python package".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a programming language, that is correct. But `python` is also the name of a conda package which contains the Python interpreter. `spyder` is an IDE, which is provided as a conda package. `jupyter` is a conda meta-package: it has no content of it's own, but it declares all the dependencies to other packages implementing Jupyter notebooks.

`conda list` or `conda env export` prints the list of packages in *one* of the conda environments. You can use `-n <envname>` to tell which environment you want to list the packages for. Each environment can have a different version of the Python interpreter.

When you write a script that depends on certain packages, then you should create a new Anaconda environment for that script. Then install all the packages the script needs into *that* environment. Do NOT try to import stuff from different environments. Each environment stands for itself. The whole point of creating environments is to keep the package dependencies of different programs separate.